# Работа с массивами С++: Найти такое максимальное К, что А[i] % k = A[j] % k , для всех {i,j}

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Дан массив `A` размером `N` (1 < N < 10<sup>9</sup>). Найти такое максимальное `k`, что `А[i] % k = A[j] % k` для всех `{i,j}`.
Каким быстрым алгоритмом можно это реализовать? Кроме алгоритма обычного перебора можно искать разность элементов, а потом их минимальный НОД. Но этот метод также слишком длинный.

Comment: ищете нод первых двух элементов. Потом найденного числа и следующего. Если дошли до 1, то все, дальше нет смысла искать. В любом случае, нужно будет перебрать все числа.

Можно конечно попробовать отсортировать числа, тогда нод нужно будет искать для меньшего кол-ва чисел, но на сортировку скорее всего потратите NlogN (или просто N, если сделаете все правильно).

Comment: Меньше, чем O(N), у вас не получится, т. к. нужно подсчитать НОД у N пар. Поскольку числа ограничены, число шагов НОД O(1). В худшем случае последняя пара может повлиять на результат (например, если все числа чётные, кроме одного). А за O(N) пробегать по списку, считать разность и текущий накопленный НОД.

Comment: @VladD, ещё есть вариант использовать факторизацию одного числа и проверять остальные на делимость. Не уверен, но может быть быстрее gcd.

Answer (score 1):

Собирая воедино комментарии @KoVadim и @VladD - что-то вроде

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
T gcd(T m, T n)
{
    while(m && n) if (m < n) n %= m; else m %= n;
    return (m == T(0)) ? n : m;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    constexpr int delta = 46574;
    constexpr int rem   =  2563;
    vector<long long> v;
    v.reserve(100000);
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(rand()*delta + rem);
    }
    long long dif = abs(v[1] - v[0]);
    for(int i = 2; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        long long d2 = abs(v[i] - v[i-1]);
        dif = gcd(dif,d2);
        if (dif == 1) break;
    }
    cout << dif << endl;
}
```

Comment: Вместо `(m == T(0)) ? n : m` можно было бы просто `m + n`.

Comment: @VladD А это мысль... Спасибо!

Comment: если все значения равны, то лучше `a[0]` вместо `0` вернуть.

Answer (score 0):

`a[i] % k == a[j] % k`  для всех `(i, j)`, тогда и только тогда `(a[i] - a[j]) % k == 0`. Если `d[i] = a[i] - a[0]`, тогда `d[i] % k == 0`, то есть `k` является делителем `d[i]` разности. То есть задача сводится к тому, чтобы найти наибольший общий делитель для всех возможных разностей:

```
k = gcd(a, b, c) == gcd(gcd(a, b), c)
```

В случае `a[i] == a[j]`, учитывая `gcd(0, 0) == 0`, ответ `k = a[0]`.

Если числа читать со стандартного ввода, где они заданы в виде текста:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric> // gcd

int main()
{
  std::istream_iterator<long> numbers {std::cin}, eof;
  if (numbers == eof) // empty input
    return !std::cin.eof(); // no io error

  auto a0 = *numbers++;
  auto k = std::accumulate(numbers, eof, 0, [a0](unsigned long init, auto a) {
      return std::gcd(init, (unsigned long)std::abs(a - a0));
      });
  std::cout << (k ? k : a0) << std::endl;
  return !std::cin.eof();
}
```

[Пример](http://ideone.com/COk9CA):

```
$ g++ -std=c++1z *.cc && ./a.out <<<"120 20 30"
10
```

Если [c++17 `std::gcd()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) недоступен, то для неотрицательных чисел [можно определить `gcd()` как](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm):

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace std
{
  template<class U>
  constexpr U gcd(std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<U>::value, U> a, U b)
  {
    if (a == b)
      return a;
    if (a == 0)
      return b;
    if (b == 0)
      return a;
    // a != b and > 0
    if (a & 1) { // a is odd
      if (b & 1) {// b is odd
        // both odd, diff is even, reduce larger arg
        return (a > b) ? gcd((a - b) >> 1, b) : gcd((b - a) >> 1, a);
      } else { // a is odd, b is even
        return gcd(a, b >> 1);
      }
    } else if (b & 1) { // a is even, b is odd
      return gcd(a >> 1, b);
    }
    // a is even, b is even
    return gcd(a >> 1, b >> 1) << 1; // non tail-recursive
  }
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то, если быть въедливо-педантичным, в терминологии языка С++ утверждения `a % k == b % k` и `(a - b) % k == 0` не являются эквивалентными. Эти утверждения верны для Евклидова деления, а деление в С++ (и соответственно `%`) не являются Евклидовыми. `(3 - -2) % 5 == 0`, но `3 % 5 == 3`, а `-2 % 5  == -2`. Хотя понятно, что в условии задачи скорее всего речь идет о Евклидовом делении и классических Евклидовых остатках. А также, возможно, об исключительно неотрицательном входе.